# Error: angular is undefined in app.js

Tags: angularjs

I have the following simple html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="store">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
</head>
<body>
    
<script src="angular.min.js"  type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <p>{{Hello Angular!!}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and app.js file

```js
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('store', []);
```

I'm getting error "angular is undefined" while running HTML file under webserver. Can anyone please suggest what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: Hi Anil, Sorry! it didn't help. I'm a beginner in AngularJS and want to use minimal code to see how angularjs works.

Comment: You can learn basic here. http://www.w3schools.com/angular/

Comment: You can use  below links. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/index.html  and http://www.toptal.com/angular-js/a-step-by-step-guide-to-your-first-angularjs-app

Answer (score 2):

Please check your reference file.

like.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="store">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
</head>
<body>  
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <p>{{Hello Angular!!}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```